# How do I use rules of inferences to imply a conclusion from 4 premises?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic, predicate-logic, quantifiers

I am a little confused on how to use 4 premises to prove a conclusion. Can you please tell me if my logic is sound for the following proof:

```
1) ∀x[C(x) ∨ M(x)]
2) ∀x[¬M(x) ∨ N(x)]
3) ∀x[J(x) → ¬N(x)]
4) ∃x¬C(x)
∴ ∃x¬J(x)

5) C(a) ∨ M(a) Universal instantiation on 1
6) ¬M(a) ∨ N(a) Universal Instantiation on 2
7) C(a) ∨ N(a) Resolution on 5 and 6
8) J(a) → ¬N(a) Universal Instantiation on 3
9) ¬C(a) Existential Instantiation on 4
10) N(a) Disjunctive Syllogism on 7
11) ¬J(a) Modus tollens on 8
12) ∃x¬J(x) Existential Generalization
```

Comment: By "modus tollens" I guess you mean "modus ponens", right? Other than that, seems ok to me.

Comment: No, the OP is using modus tollens correctly, @frabala. Though technically, we'd want to go from $N(a)$ to $\lnot\lnot N(a)$ before invoking modus tollens to derive $\lnot J(a)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to invoke existential instantiation on line $(4)$ *before* invoking any universal instantiation for the proof to work.

But otherwise, you've got the main gist of how to work with the premises to derive the conclusion

Comment: And I'm getting better at these things, any tips for getting as good as you?

Comment: You're welcome! You're doing very well! I see the progress! Puzzle: my user name *spells out* the three letters in my name. ;-)

Comment: Amy? But Amy, How do I get as good as you?!

Comment: @DrJonesYu - on behalf of amWhy (I beg her pardon ...): syudying and practicing : "there is no royal road to geometry" , and mathematics and logic either ...